like google keep share, in flutter implement like this
I’d like to implement a feature in Flutter where, when I’m using a news app and click the share button, several apps show up, and when I select my app, an intent is triggered. However, I want to prevent the Flutter app from opening entirely. Instead, like the Google Keep app, I want the news app in the background to blur, and an overlay window to pop up for saving the link. No matter how much I tweak the MainActivity, the Flutter app keeps launching, and I’m unsure how to prevent this.

Unclear if you've tried: How to make a transparent app in flutter?
